# T[] parameter in string[].Foreach()

Tags: c#, arrays, foreach, lambda

I'm just getting used to using lambdas and all of that good stuff. However, I am not aware of what argument I need to provide in this case.

I am attempting to modify I string to replace all instances of an entry in a dictionary with it's value, nothing too fancy, I could do this with a simple `foreach` loop but I'm trying to use this as a learning exercise.

My code so far is as follows:

```
        string maskString = Masks[alias];
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"({[\w+|\d]+})");
        MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(maskString);
        string[] constants = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();
        string maskedString = "";
        if (constants.All(constant => Constants.ContainsKey(constant)))
        {
            constants.ForEach(constant => maskedString = maskedString.Replace(constant, Constants[constant]));
        }
```

However, I am receiving this error: `There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'action' of 'Array.ForEach<T>(T[], Action<T>)'`. It seems to me that I am providing the action in the form of a `lambda` expression, but I have no idea why it wants another array or what array I should give it.

I have tried providing it with `null`,`string[]` and `new [] {typeof(string)}` but these just cause more errors.

Is it possible for me to conduct this operation using this structure or would it be more practical just to use a traditional `foreach` loop?

Comment: Array.ForEach is not an extension method (it's just a static method of Array), so use it like this : `Array.ForEach(constants, constant => maskedString = maskedString.Replace(constant, Constants[constant]));` anyway, I would prefer a standard foreach loop when "side-effects" are involved

Comment: Keep it simple and maintainable. LINQ statements can be useful, but they can also be difficult to interpret.

Comment: @digEmAll I noticed that just before you commented, by looking at the docs (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zecdkyw2(v=vs.110).aspx) I didn't actually see this comment until I'd posted my answer, but thank you! Out of interest, why is it an extension method for most `IEnumerable<T>`s but not `[]`s?

Comment: @JamesHughes It's *not* an extension method at all. For `Array.ForEach`, it's a static non-extension method. For `List<T>.ForEach`, it's a regular instance method. For other `IEnumerable<T>`, there's no standard `ForEach` that can be called, extension method or not.

Comment: @hvd right, I'm with you. My mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anytime you would better use Aggregate function:

```
maskedString = constants.Aggregate(maskedString, (current, constant ) => current.Replace(constant , Constants[constant]));
```

Comment: I like this... I like this a lot. Thanks!

Comment: @JamesHughes  thanks, could you be than so kind and mark answer as a solution :)

Answer (score 6):

It would appear that this is an incorrect use of the `.ForEach()` method, it is a `static` method of the `Array` class, not an extension method. There are two ways to perform this correctly:

First, uses the Array.ForEach() static method and provides the array as the first parameter:

```
Array.ForEach(constants,constant => maskedString = maskedString.Replace(constant, Constants[constant]));
```

Second, casts the array to a `List<T>` first:

```
constants.ToList().ForEach(constant => maskedString = maskedString.Replace(constant, Constants[constant]));
```

The second method will not modify the original array and consequently if this was required you'd have to do `myArray = myArray.ToList().ForEach().ToArray()`. Thanks Chris for this point.

Comment: Note that your second will *not* work perfectly. It will create a new List object and then operate on that object. The original constants array will not be modified. Instead you'd need to do `constants = (your expression).ToArray();`

Comment: @Chris I don't actually modify the original array, I simply use it to modify a separate string, but this is an important clarification for anyone else reading this

Comment: My point is that without an assignment your second does absolutely nothing. Its not just "if this was required" because if its not required you might as well not put in your line of code.

Comment: I'm not sure we're on the same page, I'm not modifying my array at all. I'm modifying a totally external variable `maskedString`: why wouldn't that work?

Comment: Oh, sorry. My bad. I hadn't noticed that it was writing to a variable inside the lambda. I'm too used to more traditional LINQ type things where you are just projecting, filtering, etc. and then returning the results. The OP still seems to have an issue that maskedString is being initialized to empty and thus the replace is unlikely to replace anything but that is the OP's problem. Your code looks sound now you have pointed out that I should actually read it. :)

Comment: Aha cheers mate, no worries, I am the OP, I worked it out before anyone else answered so rather than delete the question I thought I'd post my solution

Comment: Oh dear. I clearly should not be commenting on here before I've got some caffeine in me. :)